# 1 Off bulk push to Eventhub

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-eventhub

I have setup an Eventhub and configured the azure Sign In Logs to stream to the Eventhub which is then being pulled into our analytics platform.

This is working fine, however i'm only getting data from the time I configured the stream.

Is there a way I can do a 1 off bulk push of all sign in logs in azure the event hub. Basically so I can pull the last 30 days worth of data into our analytics platform and then continue to stream from now on?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your post!

I'm not sure if this is possible, but you can try downloading your [Azure AD Sign-in logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-download-logs#how-to-do-it) as JSON, and uploading the JSON file to your [Log Analytics Workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/data/upload-logs?tabs=windows#upload-logs-to-azure-log-analytics-workspace-in-direct-mode).